# Is there an already existing theory to quadratic/nonlinear functionals/operators?

Tags: functional-analysis

I'm curious if there is a theory that is dealing with "functionals" or rather mappings $F:X\to \mathbb{K}$ that satisfy something like:
\begin{align*}
(i) & F(x+y) = F(x) + F(y) + \frac{1}{2} [ F(x+y) - F(x-y) ] \; \forall x,y \in X \\
(ii) & F( \alpha x ) = \alpha^2 F(x) \; \forall x \in X, \alpha \in \mathbb{K} ,
\end{align*}
where we may assume $X$ to be sufficently nice (e.g. a Banach space). Applications could be differential equations of the form:
\begin{align*}
\partial_t f = \partial_x f^2 .
\end{align*}

Comment: Consider a linear map $T:X\to X^*$ and then look at $X\to\Bbb K$, $x\mapsto T(x)\,[x]$. This is quadratic - with a little work you can see that every quadratic is of this form.

Comment: This is called a quadratic form: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_form

Comment: Thank you for your answers, especially the one of @s.harp.